# Cosmosdb query metrics not returned in postman

Tags: postman, azure-cosmosdb

I have a postman collection that I'm using to execute requests against cosmos db. I have included the populate query metrics option in the request header as shown, but I don't receive the x-ms-documentdb-query-metrics in the response? Any ideas please?

[image]

Comment: There is no code. It is just a postman request

Comment: Hi,any progress?

Comment: I logged a support ticket with the MS team. Have just received a reply. Will let you know :-)

Comment: Any differences between us?

Comment: Got a response from MS. Looks as though it has to be a POST with the body containing the query. Hence why isquery set to True. Just waiting for confirmation that this header is not applicable for stored procedures

Answer (score 0):

I could get `querymetrics` in postman. Please refer to my details:

[image]

***My request:***

```
x-ms-date:mon, 28 may 2018 07:14:25 gmt
x-ms-version:2017-02-22
Authorization:***
Content-Type:application/query+json
x-ms-documentdb-populatequerymetrics:True
Content-Length:43
x-ms-documentdb-isquery:true
```

***My response:***

[image]

I suggest you using Fiddler tool to grab the package and analyze it to find the differences.

Any concern,please let me know.